# Was Tajmahal Tejo Mahal?

Tags: india

History says that the Taj Mahal was built by Mughal emperor Shah Jahan in memory of his third wife, Mumtaz Mahal. However, I've also read many [stories](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/true_story_of_the_taj_mahal.htm) claiming that it was a Lord Shiva temple earlier.

What's the truth?

Comment: Seems like all the arguments are basically attributed to P. N. Oak, who wrote a book called "Taj Mahal - The True Story" in 1956.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no scholarly literature (like publications in reputed academic peer-reviewed papers etc) supporting the theory that it was a temple earlier. Till such materials are available, it would be wise to consider such stories as myths.

Comment: I put that as religious propaganda.